# Overwrite existing Excel data on existing sheet using Pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

Hope you can help me out. I have been searching for already a long time but cannot get this working.

I have defined a dataset using Pandas from an Excel, made some changes, and now I want to write the updated data back to the same Excel.

My understanding is that pd.ExcelWriter should be able to do this according the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html). Also, I want to have the dataset written starting from specific rows and columns position. Leaving the rest of the Excel sheets intact.

The problem I have is that the code writes the dataset to Excel on a new blank sheet, instead of the specified sheetname: "SheetX". The new blank sheet is called "SheetX1".

I have searched Google and also many similar topics on this website, but I cannot find a solution that works.

In summary: I want to overwrite an existing Excel workbook in an existing worksheet, overwriting the data based on the specified starting and rows and columns.

Many thanks in advance if you can help me out with this one.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("Excel1.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode = "a") as writer:
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="SheetX", startrow=5, startcol=8)
```

Please let me know if you need anymore clarification on this. Happy to answer.

Comment: As per the documentation, if you try to write to an existing sheet in `append mode`. it will error out. The best way would be to format the dataframe as per your understanding and then write to the file with `if_sheet_exists` flag set to `replace`, the default for the flag is `error`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I didn't note the reference to Append, thanks for pointing that out. However, the sheet is full of formulas that I actually do not want to alter. How should the if_sheet_exists with flag to be written in my code? I am new to programming. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it  like this :

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("Excel1.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode = "a", if_sheet_exists = 'replace') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="SheetX", startrow=5, startcol=8)
```